# AeroSpike Atomic counter limit

Tags: aerospike

I'm trying to use AeroSpike Atomic counter for load balancing coming txn to a sequence of users. I plan to use the counter to track the number of coming txn and make % with users number to get who to assign.

Does this counter has a limit? If yes, what is limit? And what would happen if the the limit is hit? Would it be reset to 0 automatically?

Or is there any other suggestions to do the load balancing in high concurrency?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if that's the best strategy for load balancing in high concurrency or what happens if you hit the limit.

But as for the limit itself -> according to [Atomic Counters using Aerospike](https://medium.com/aerospike-developer-blog/atomic-counters-using-aerospike-1f9c9730c903) blog post an atomic counter is represented by a Bin that stores 64-bit unsigned integer.

64-bit unsigned integer value starts at 0 and the highest value is 2^64-1 (18,446,744,073,709,551,615), keep in mind that unsigned integers cannot represent negative values.